# NameError: name X' is not defined - django rest framework

Tags: python, api, aplicação-web, django, django-rest-framework

Seguindo o [tutorial](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/#writing-regular-django-views-using-our-serializer) para a criação de API com o DRF, encontrei dificuldades durante o mapeamento das urls. Ao executar o `'python manage.py runserver'`, recebo o seguinte erro `path('', include(loja.urls)), NameError: name 'loja' is not defined`. Não consigo enxergar onde estou falhando nesse processo e espero poder contar com ajuda.

estrutura do projeto:

```
sistema/
  loja/
    urls.py
    views.py
  sistema/
    urls.py
```

*views.py*

```
@csrf_exempt
def store_list(request):

if request.method == 'GET':
    store= Lojas.objects.all()
    serializer = LojasSerializer(store, many=True)
    return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)

elif request.method == 'POST':
    data = JSONParser().parse(request)
    serializer = LojasSerializer(data=data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
    return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

*loja/urls.py*

```
from django.urls import path
from loja import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('loja/',  views.store_list),
]
```

sistema/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework import routers
from loja import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include(loja.urls)),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
]
```

erro de saída:

`path('', include(loja.urls)), NameError: name 'loja' is not defined`

EDIT: Após o erro de saída, outra mensagem de erro aparece e minha operação é encerrada automaticamente.

*erro:*

```
SError: [WinError 123] A sintaxe do nome do arquivo, do nome do diretório ou do rótulo do volume está incorreta: '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>'
```

Acredito que eu tenha seguido com atenção ao tutorial, por isso não consigo entender aonde estou errando.

Comment: Se vires a [documentação sobre namespaces de urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#namespaces-and-include), tens de passar como uma string: `path('', include('loja.urls'))`

Comment: @drec4s Eu tentei passar como string. Infelizmente o resultado foi o mesmo.

Comment: Então o problema é com o nome do módulo. É `loja` ou `lojas`? Outra coisa, adicionaste essa app nas `INSTALLED_APPS` nas settings?

Comment: No caso seria loja mesmo. Sim, eu adicionei nas INSTALLED_APPS, mas persiste o mesmo erro :(

Answer (score 1):

Oi, importa desta forma:

**urls.py**

```
from [a_tua_app_name].loja import views
```

NOTA: Teste caso substitui [a_tua_app_name] pelo nome da tua app.

Ou

```
from .loja import views
```

Ou

```
from django.urls import path
import [a_tua_app_name].views

urlpatterns = [
    path('loja/',  [a_tua_app_name].views.store_list, name='loja'),
]
```

Comment: O formato já está setado dessa maneira. Eu realmente não consigo entender o que acontece para gerar esse erro. Fiz um edite mostrando outra mensagem de erro que aparece após essa. Seria muito importante para mim que esse tópico não morresse.